# Eclipse, QueryDSL and Spring Roo working together?

Tags: java, maven, jpa, spring-roo, querydsl

I'm trying to set up a maven-based SpringRoo project with QueryDSL in Eclipse and cannot seem to get the generator working when I have Roo enabled.  If I create a plain project, and populate my pom.xml with the necessary querydsl plugins/dependencies, my metamodel classes are automatically generated.

However, if I switch to a basic ROO project, and add the necessary querydsl plugins/dependencies, then no metamodel classes are generated.

These are the additions I've put in my pom.xml:

```
<!-- Querydsl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

---

```
    <plugin>
        <!-- Requires mysema m2e plugin (http://ilx.github.com/m2e-querydsl/repository/0.0.5/) -->
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>process</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <logOnlyOnError>true</logOnlyOnError>
                    <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/apt</outputDirectory>
                    <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
                <classifier>apt</classifier>
                <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    <!-- right now this seems needed -->

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>add-source</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>target/generated-sources/apt</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I am using Eclipse 3.7, m2e 1.2, Java 6. I also have the mysema m2e plugin installed from http://ilx.github.com/m2e-querydsl/repository/0.0.5/.

Does anyone have a working configuration with Roo and QueryDSL that works?  If so, can you share your pom.xml please?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason that I do not understand, I needed to add a spring-tx dependency to my pom.xml.  Once that was in place, the metamodel classes were automatically generated.  There was a caveat however, I needed to manually annotate my entities with @Entity and not rely on Roo to annotate it via aspects.  Finally, updating my plugin to 1.0.7 removed the need to use maven-build-helper.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


        <!-- QueryDSL plugin -->
        <plugin>
        <!-- Requires mysema m2e plugin (http://ilx.github.com/m2e-querydsl/repository/0.0.5/) -->
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>process</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/apt</outputDirectory>
                    <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
                <classifier>apt</classifier>
                <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Sample Java Bean:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaEntity
@Entity
public class Client {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Date created_on;
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you needed to add spring-tx. Do you have a multi-module project and this was to a "non-entities" pom?

Comment: Not entirely sure why I needed spring-tx.  I didn't spend the time to figure out why.  This is not a multi-module project - just a basic dummy project that I wanted to add QueryDSL to.  @TimoWestkamper is actually the one who suggested the change.  And I noticed it worked, so I didn't put much more effort into figuring it out.  Let me know if you do.

Comment: I'm exactually going down the JPASpecificationExecutor for the time being so I won't be needeing QueryDSL just yet. Thanks for the info.

Comment: spring-tx was needed for compilation, but APT is run before compilation and crashes with weird exceptions, if dependencies are missing, I am not sure how it can be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor needs javax.persistence.Entity annotated Java files. If you use other annotations or add the Entity annotation at runtime, no classes will be generated.

See this chapter of the Querydsl reference docs for classloader based code generation as an alternative to APT http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.8.2/reference/html/ch03s02.html

Comment: I've tried with the same entity that works in a non-roo project but the metamodel classes are not generated in the roo project automatically.  I suspect that there may be a strange plugin conflict or some race condition, but I don't know where it is coming from.

Comment: Querydsl 3.0 is going to have Spring Roo support https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/318

Answer (score 0):

There's old discussion about this topic, where Ken Rimple states that " I had trouble getting anything to work on the QueryDSL generators with the pre-built ITDs. Since the actual class doesn't have an @Entity on it (until the AspectJ compiler comes in and adds it) when the QueryDSL is generating code, it doesn't see them as entities."

http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=51012&tstart=15

To me this seems to be something one could try to tweak by changing order in which maven is using plugins (lifecycle phases).